# Exporting trained TensorFlow models to C++

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, bazel

I am trying to export trained TensorFlow models to C++ using [freeze_graph.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py). I am trying to export the ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17 model using the following syntax:

```
bazel build tensorflow/python/tools:freeze_graph && \
bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph \
--input_graph=frozen_inference_graph.pb \
--input_checkpoint=model.ckpt \
--output_graph=/tmp/frozen_graph.pb --output_node_names=softmax
```

The terminal said that the build was successful but showed the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/my_username/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py", line 350, in <module>
    app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/home/my_username/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 124, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/home/my_username/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py", line 249, in main
    FLAGS.saved_model_tags)
  File "/home/my_username/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py", line 227, in freeze_graph
    input_graph_def = _parse_input_graph_proto(input_graph, input_binary)
  File "/home/my_username/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py", line 171, in _parse_input_graph_proto
    text_format.Merge(f.read(), input_graph_def)
  File "/home/my_username/.cache/bazel/_bazel_my_username/3572bc2aff1de1dd37356cf341944e54/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.runfiles/protobuf_archive/python/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 525, in Merge
    descriptor_pool=descriptor_pool)
  File "/home/my_username/.cache/bazel/_bazel_my_username/3572bc2aff1de1dd37356cf341944e54/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.runfiles/protobuf_archive/python/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 579, in MergeLines
    return parser.MergeLines(lines, message)
  File "/home/my_username/.cache/bazel/_bazel_my_username/3572bc2aff1de1dd37356cf341944e54/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.runfiles/protobuf_archive/python/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 612, in MergeLines
    self._ParseOrMerge(lines, message)
  File "/home/my_username/.cache/bazel/_bazel_my_username/3572bc2aff1de1dd37356cf341944e54/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.runfiles/protobuf_archive/python/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 627, in _ParseOrMerge
    self._MergeField(tokenizer, message)
  File "/home/my_username/.cache/bazel/_bazel_my_username/3572bc2aff1de1dd37356cf341944e54/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.runfiles/protobuf_archive/python/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 671, in _MergeField
    name = tokenizer.ConsumeIdentifierOrNumber()
  File "/home/my_username/.cache/bazel/_bazel_my_username/3572bc2aff1de1dd37356cf341944e54/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.runfiles/protobuf_archive/python/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 1144, in ConsumeIdentifierOrNumber
    raise self.ParseError('Expected identifier or number, got %s.' % result)
google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 2:1 : Expected identifier or number, got `.
```

On running that command again, I got this message:

```
WARNING: /home/my_username/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:1814:1: in includes attribute of cc_library rule //tensorflow/core:framework_headers_lib: '../../external/nsync/public' resolves to 'external/nsync/public' not below the relative path of its package 'tensorflow/core'. This will be an error in the future. Since this rule was created by the macro 'cc_header_only_library', the error might have been caused by the macro implementation in /home/my_username/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl:1138:30
WARNING: /home/my_username/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:1814:1: in includes attribute of cc_library rule //tensorflow/core:framework_headers_lib: '../../external/nsync/public' resolves to 'external/nsync/public' not below the relative path of its package 'tensorflow/core'. This will be an error in the future. Since this rule was created by the macro 'cc_header_only_library', the error might have been caused by the macro implementation in /home/my_username/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl:1138:30
WARNING: /home/my_username/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/learn/BUILD:15:1: in py_library rule //tensorflow/contrib/learn:learn: target '//tensorflow/contrib/learn:learn' depends on deprecated target '//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:exporter': No longer supported. Switch to SavedModel immediately.
WARNING: /home/my_username/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/learn/BUILD:15:1: in py_library rule //tensorflow/contrib/learn:learn: target '//tensorflow/contrib/learn:learn' depends on deprecated target '//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:gc': No longer supported. Switch to SavedModel immediately.
INFO: Analysed target //tensorflow/python/tools:freeze_graph (0 packages loaded).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //tensorflow/python/tools:freeze_graph up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.419s, Critical Path: 0.00s
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/my_username/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py", line 350, in <module>
    app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/home/my_username/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 124, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/home/my_username/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py", line 249, in main
    FLAGS.saved_model_tags)
  File "/home/my_username/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py", line 227, in freeze_graph
    input_graph_def = _parse_input_graph_proto(input_graph, input_binary)
  File "/home/my_username/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py", line 171, in _parse_input_graph_proto
    text_format.Merge(f.read(), input_graph_def)
  File "/home/my_username/.cache/bazel/_bazel_my_username/3572bc2aff1de1dd37356cf341944e54/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.runfiles/protobuf_archive/python/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 525, in Merge
    descriptor_pool=descriptor_pool)
  File "/home/my_username/.cache/bazel/_bazel_my_username/3572bc2aff1de1dd37356cf341944e54/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.runfiles/protobuf_archive/python/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 579, in MergeLines
    return parser.MergeLines(lines, message)
  File "/home/my_username/.cache/bazel/_bazel_my_username/3572bc2aff1de1dd37356cf341944e54/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.runfiles/protobuf_archive/python/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 612, in MergeLines
    self._ParseOrMerge(lines, message)
  File "/home/my_username/.cache/bazel/_bazel_my_username/3572bc2aff1de1dd37356cf341944e54/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.runfiles/protobuf_archive/python/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 627, in _ParseOrMerge
    self._MergeField(tokenizer, message)
  File "/home/my_username/.cache/bazel/_bazel_my_username/3572bc2aff1de1dd37356cf341944e54/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.runfiles/protobuf_archive/python/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 671, in _MergeField
    name = tokenizer.ConsumeIdentifierOrNumber()
  File "/home/my_username/.cache/bazel/_bazel_my_username/3572bc2aff1de1dd37356cf341944e54/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.runfiles/protobuf_archive/python/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 1144, in ConsumeIdentifierOrNumber
    raise self.ParseError('Expected identifier or number, got %s.' % result)
google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 2:1 : Expected identifier or number, got `.
```

I am exporting the ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17 just as for practice. I intend to export my own trained models and test the output with this [program](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc).
I have built TensorFlow 1.5 using Bazel v0.11.1. I validated the installation using the following code snippet provided in the TensorFlow website;

```
# Python
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

I also ran the object detection iPython example notebook and it worked.

I am using Ubuntu 17.10.1 on  a laptop with an Intel Core i5-8250U CPU, 8GB RAM, 1TB HDD and an NVIDIA MX150(2 GB) GPU. Please help. How do I export a trained model to C++?

Answer (score 0):

in order to export object detection models I use the export_inference_graph.py code in research/object-detection. Here's an example of running the code:

```
python3 export_inference_graph.py \
--input_type image_tensor \
--pipeline_config_path path/to/model.config \    
--trained_checkpoint_prefix path/to/model.ckpt-CHECKPOINTNUMBER \    
--output_directory path/to/frozen_inference_graph
```

Then I use the created frozen_inference_graph.pb with a C++ code that is essentially the same as [label_image](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc) with little modifications to run for a detection model rather than a classification one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually found out another way to do what i needed using the [Deep Learning support in OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API).
This also does not require TensorFlow to be installed in the machine running the classification.